# How to handle __invoke() method does not exist in PHP?

Tags: php

The magical **__call()** and **__callStatic** can pretty much handle any non existing method on the class, but is there a way to handle a non existing magical method on a class?!

---

Here's an example on why I need this:

I have a class called **DoSomething**:

```
class DoSomething{
   public function ok(){
      echo 'Something!';
   }
}
```

I want to call this class as a function for a reason! which should call the **__invoke** function of that class:

```
$doSomething = new DoSomething();

$doSomething();
```

Normally by doing that, the class should look for the **__invoke** function, however in my case I don't to have that function declared on my class (**DoSomething**), instead I want to be able to call another function (such as the **ok()**) if the **__invoke** doesn't exist.

I was expecting something like this to work, but of course it didn't :)

```
public function __call($class, $arguments)
{
    $object = IoC::resolve($class);

    $object->ok(...$arguments);
}
```

The main goal is to use the class as a function, without having to declare the __invoke method. Handle the function does not exist error and call another function instead.

I think that would be really cool :D I appreciate suggestions or other solutions to achieve this.

Comment: Magic! Really? Just declare `__invoke()`!

Comment: @localheinz Really :D I have a good reason why I don't want to declare that. Otherwise I wouldn't ask the question. I'm refactoring a large code and declaring the __invoke() is not a valid option. I should hack it somehow to keep the code backward compatible...

Comment: Honestly... if you need to invoke objects as if they're methods, just write the __invoke implementations. You could dick around coming up with some grim work around perhaps, but that will just make your code a mess, harder to follow, and ultimately harder to maintain. Do your future self or subsequent maintainers a favour and just write a clear implementation of your intent, using the tools the language provides and respect the Principle of Least Astonishment. What you're trying to do is false economy.

Comment: @AdamCameron so your answer is don't do it :D I know the consequences and still wanna do it! but thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 3):

### Internal solution

#### Extract an `abstract` class

You could extract an `abstract` class and have your classes extend it:

```
<?php

abstract class Invokable
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->ok();
    }

    abstract public function ok();
}

class DoSomething extends Invokable
{
    public function ok()
    {
        echo 'Something';
    }
}

$doSomething = new DoSomething();

echo $doSomething();
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/m0ih8

#### Extract a trait

You could extract a trait and have your classes use it:

```
<?php

trait InvokableTrait
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->ok();
    }
}

class DoSomething
{
    use InvokableTrait;

    public function ok()
    {
        echo 'Something';
    }
}

$doSomething = new DoSomething();

echo $doSomething();
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/ftUfI

### External Solution

#### Create a proxy

You could create a proxy (a decorator) that composes the object that is not invokable:

```
<?php

class InvokableDecorator
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct($decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated; 
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        /**
         * delegate to decorated object if the method exists
         */ 
        if (method_exists($this->decorated, $name)) {
            return $this->decorated->{$name}($arguments);
        }
    }

    public function __invoke() 
    {        
        return $this->decorated->ok();
    }        
}

class DoSomething
{
    public function ok()
    {
        echo 'Something';
    }
}

$doSomething = new InvokableDecorator(new DoSomething());

echo $doSomething();
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/C3XEX

#### Create a handler

You could create a handler that takes care of determining this externally:

```
<?php

class Handler
{
    public function handle($subject)
    {
        if (is_callable($subject)) {
            return $subject();
        }

        if (method_exists($subject, 'ok')) {
            return $subject->ok();
        }

        throw new \BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
            'Unable to handle instance of "%s"',
            get_class($subject)
        ));
    }        
}

class DoSomething
{
    public function ok()
    {
        echo 'Something';
    }
}

$handler = new Handler();

echo $handler->handle(new DoSomething());
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/E0NVs

Comment: This is a good option. However, I didn't want to do that since I'll have to write that piece of code everywhere I want to use the DoSomething and every other similar class (I have 200 Class they all have the same function Ok() and I want to call that instead). I prefer the Internally option as it's more portable solution.

Comment: If need be, you could extract a) an `abstract` class and have your classes extend it, or b) extract a trait and have your classes use it, or c) decorate your classes.

Comment: Adjusted the answer to show you more concrete examples of what I meant by my comment!